# "xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 0.50" doesn't work on ubuntu 22.04 LTS terminal

Tags: brightness, xrandr

Before I was using **ubuntu 20.04 LTS** and the same command works fine. Now I change my laptop to MI Notebook Pro and install **ubuntu 22.04 LTS** which is a latest version of ubuntu and now **xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 0.50** didn't seems to work. If anyone knows the solution for this problem please comment because I have some eye related issues that's why I need to extra reduce the brightness.

Answer (score 0):

Use soft-brightness extension to control brightness in Ubuntu 22.04:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1625/soft-brightness/

Once installed, you can reduce brightness from top-right menu.

Guide to install gnome-extensions: https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/

`sudo apt update` was not working at first when I installed Ubuntu 22.04, I changed server to `Main Server` in `Software & Updates -> Ubuntu Software -> Download from` and the issue is solved

Comment: Thank You very much. Its working.